# Get http location

Tags: php, http, get

Привет всем. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как получить из хедера location?

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример, как строка запроса определяется в фреймворке Yii (который скопирован из Zend Framework):

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L529

```
<?php
/** Исключение при обработке входящего запроса */
class RequestException extends Exception {};

/** Класс для обработки входящего запроса */
class HttpRequest {
    private $_requestUri;

    /**
     * Returns the request URI portion for the currently requested URL.
     * @return string the request URI portion for the currently requested URL.
     * @throws RequestException if the request URI cannot be determined due to improper server configuration
     */
    public function getRequestUri() {
        if (is_null($this->_requestUri))
        {
            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'])) // IIS
                $this->_requestUri=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];
            elseif(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
            {
                $this->_requestUri=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
                {
                    if(strpos($this->_requestUri,$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])!==false)
                        $this->_requestUri=preg_replace('/^\w+:\/\/[^\/]+/','',$this->_requestUri);
                }
                else
                    $this->_requestUri=preg_replace('/^(http|https):\/\/[^\/]+/i','',$this->_requestUri);
            }
            else
                throw new Exception('HttpRequest is unable to determine the request URI');
        }
        return $this->_requestUri;
    }
}

// пример использования
$request = new HttpRequest;
echo 'Request URI: ', $request->getRequestUri();
?>
```

Comment: побывал $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
не получаю

Comment: @Vasja Pupkin

1) проб**о**вал
2) Реферер - это предыдущая страница, на которой был пользователь, она и не должна выдавать текущий адрес
3) Выше приведен рабочий пример; если вкратце, то, скорее всего, полный адрес страницы можно составить из `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` и `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Да, для получения протокола и порта в Yii другой метод этого класса. 

    https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L331
    public function getHostInfo() { }

Мир сложен. Там так много проверок, что я его приводить не стал.

Comment: В отличие от window.location на стороне PHP нельзя получить хэш запроса (слово "page" из URL вида http://хост/#page в PHP неизвестно)

Comment: Ага,понял,как тогда можно получить?
суть в том что я курлом посылаю пост запрос,после которого меня редиректит на site.ru/?page=4356436453,мне нужно узнать именно эти цыфры

Comment: Это ж совсем другой вопрос. Уточни постановку и получишь ответ. Кратко - в настройках запроса через curl отключить редиректы и прочитать заголовки ответа.